# Get the right field from an abstract class hierarchy?

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class, field, hierarchy

I have an Abstract class A

```
public abstract class A{
    private int x;
    public void doSomethingToX{...};
    public int getX(){
     return x;
    }
```

I have 7 classes that extend A, each of the 7 implement doSomethingToX in the same way, so I defined it in class A. If class B extends A, and I call B.doSomethingToX(), and then I call B.getX(), will I get B's X value or will I get A's?

In my real program I have an ArrayList of A objects

```
ArrayList<A> list;
```

and I call:

```
  list.add(new B());
   list.get(index).doSomethingToX();
   list.get(index).getX();
```

Will I get A's x or B's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't override getX() on extended classes you will get x from A.

if you override getX() you will get the value returned on overrides method.

example:

```
A a = new B(); a.getX();
B b = new B(); b.getX();
```

All the above lines will return the value of getX() overridden on Class B.

If this method was not overriden on Class B then you will get the value defined on Class A.

Comment: So I have to write getX() for each class? Is there a way I can write it only once?

Comment: If you not override getX() on Class B then you will get the value defined on getX() of Class A.

Comment: Ok thank you. Since you answered first, I will award you Best Answer

Comment: "will I get B's X value or will I get A's" I feel this is quite a misleading statement. There is only one x and it exists for class B (class A can never be instantiated after all). What you really mean is will you get the result of getX() in class A or getX() in class B. As already stated, unless the method is overridden, there is only one getX method.